# Call to a member function isAdmin() on null

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Hey I'm learning laravel v5.2 and working on user authentication system and making some check using User modal to check is login user is admin or not.But when I'm try to get login user by using **Auth::user()**  I'm getting blank value in return.

```
 use App\User;

 Route::get('/', function () {

   $user = Auth::user();

   // $user = User::find(1);

   if($user->isAdmin()){
      return "Admin";
    }

    return "Normal User";

  });

  Route::get('/access',['middleware'=>'role',function(){
     return "This is middleware";  
  }]);


Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

   Route::auth();
   Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `web` middleware is not running on that specific route. Said middleware is the one in charge of setting all the authentication along with session creation, hence you won't get an authenticated user on a route which isn't making use of the `web` middleware.

It's a bad practice to create callback routes by the way, but just for the sake of this particular case:

```
 Route::get('/', function () {

   $user = Auth::user();

   // $user = User::find(1);

   if($user->isAdmin()){
      return "Admin";
    }

    return "Normal User";

  })->middleware('web');
```